# Firefox back issue

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using a menu that switches from standard state to select state for an item by reading the current url

```
var where  = document.location.href;
```

My issue is that when using Firefox, if I switch to some items from the menu (for instance, I click home, donwload, contact) and press the back button the url is not read correctly so 2 items remain on the selected state. This only happens in Firefox (I've tested already in Explorer, Chrome and Opera)

So what I'm trying to ask: is there a way to handle the so called back button action in/for Firefox so I can fix my menu issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Determine the select state on the server-side, this won't be an issue.

Comment: Hello,

It appears that this is the way to go, nevertheless Firefox's behavior is strange in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kerry said I would also go with server side. But you can mix them both. Use server side to give your menu items a class:

```
// this will put the class selected on the link
<a href="..." class="<?=($opt=='this-links-name'?'selected':''>" link name </a>
```

And then use Javascript to look and "highlight" those classes. Though I would probably go with CSS for colors and style and JS only for transitions and such.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I went on the server-side way this time